# Infinite horizontal scrolling in MKMapView

Tags: ios, scroll, mkmapview, mapkit, infinite

I am trying to figure out how to get a `MKMapView` to scroll horizontally endlessly (as if spinning a globe) as per the Maps application in the iPhone. Is there a setting within **MapKit**? or would I have to setup two `MKMapViews` side by side?

Any advice or information is greatly appreciated.

I have tried searching on this forums but it seems this question has not been asked before. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Regards.

Leon

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in MapKit.  If you want this I suggest filing a feature request for this.

If you want this in iOS I suggest using the new Google Maps iOS SDK available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/).

UPDATE - This is now possible in iOS7 and later natively

Comment: Actually it is possible as the Maps application in the iPhone is doing exactly that, which is why I am curious as to whether it is a new feature or it requires a little more programming. For reference my iOS version is 6.1.3. Thanks for replying.

Comment: true, but with map kit this isn't possible yet

Comment: Correct. This is not possible in your own code as my answer said!

Comment: @LeeArmstrong: I have seen the Groupon application (https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/groupon-deals-coupons-shopping/id352683833?mt=8) is having Apple map with infinite scrolling... so I am not able to guess what they might have done... have you found any solution with Apple Map?

Comment: It has been in native MapKit now since I think iOS7!